# Chronometer in textview xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, textview, chronometer

I want to display chronometer in textview while user is logged in in `xamarin.android` app. How to do this?

Here are parts of my code:

Here are parts of my code:

xaml

```
<TextView
            android:text="Dzisiaj pracujesz już:\n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="226dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"/>
```

LoginViewModel class

```
if (lg)
            {
                _appVariables.UserName = UserName;
                _appVariables.logDate = DateTime.Now;
                _appVariables.isLogged = true;
                 await GoToDashboard.Handle(Unit.Default);
                 logging = _appVariables.logDate.ToString();


            }
```

Comment: I'm trying to define what a chronometer would actually be, I'm not overly familiar with the term in relation to an app. What would it need to display.

Comment: a timer, time goes up

Comment: It has to count updated time that has passed, since the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what do you need to implement,but here is a sample to display chronometer in textview:

```
private TextView tvTime;
private TimerCallback timerDelegate;
private int second;
private Timer _dispatcherTimer;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
     base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
     SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity);
     FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.take).Click += CameraActivity_Click;
     tvTime = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.time);
     timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(Tick);
    }

 private void Tick(object state)
    {
        this.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            tvTime.Text = (second++).ToString();
        });
    }
```

after click the button,the textview will start count each second.